# Is it possible to list contacts filtered by owner's ID using Mautic REST API?

Tags: mautic

Looking at the Mautic Developer Documentation:

https://developer.mautic.org/#list-contacts

It appears there's a search query parameter to filter the result set. Is it possible to specify which attribute and value to filter against?

I'm certain there are contacts own by a user with ID=3 and tried a few ways to pass the name value pair into the search parameter without success:

http:///api/contacts?search=owner.id:3

http:///api/contacts?search=owner_id:3

http:///api/contacts?search=owner.id%3D3

Both scenario return empty dataset. I also try just putting in the owner's username in the search parameter. That also yields no results. Are there a list of attributes the search parameter work against?

Answer (score 2):

To do the owner filter, use

**`[mauticURL]/api/contacts?search=owner:[ownername]`**